# Using URL to identify selected button

Tags: parsing, url, servlets

I have a page with multiple buttons with each button has a name and value attribute. After clicking the button the page would be redirected to another page which is given in action attribute of form with the selected button name and value.

I want to retrive the selected button name or ID which is appended with the url in the next page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you give the button a name, then it's just available as request parameter.

E.g.

```
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
```

with in servlet

```
if (request.getParameter("add") != null) {
    // Add button was pressed.
} else if (request.getParameter("edit") != null) {
    // Edit button was pressed.
} else if (request.getParameter("delete") != null) {
    // Delete button was pressed.
} else {
    // Handle exceptional/alternative case yourself.
}
```

or in JSP

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty param.add}">
        Add button was pressed.
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${not empty param.edit}">
        Edit button was pressed.
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${not empty param.delete}">
        Delete button was pressed.
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        Handle exceptional/alternative case yourself.
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```